# Concatenate two xml/html Files with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i'm trying to concatenate two Files. One of them XML and the other HTML. I'm probably making a stupid mistake, i'm not very familiar with handling XSLT.

I apply an XSL file to a XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REPORT>
   <YASCA />
   <AOSCAT />
</REPORT>
```

And this is what the XSL file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
        <xsl:template match="//YASCA">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('abc.xml')"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="//AOSCAT">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('xyz.html')"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

And this is the error-message i get from AltovaXMLSpy after applying the XSLT and trying to save the created document:

```
XML Production Error: Character 'A' following the text '<' does not fulfill production 'Misc'.
```

It occurs at the point in the file where the first tag (the container for the contents of the XML file) ends and the second one (the container for the contents of the HTML file) starts.

```
</YASCA><AOSCAT>
```

I also tried different approaches of combining the files (some of them i found on stackoverflow), but none of them worked and this seems to be the most favorable since it's simple should does exactly what i want.

I hope i sufficiently explained my Problem and someone can help me.

Best regards

Marty

Comment: Almost sufficiently, please also add both `abc.xml` and `xyz.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in general HTML is not XML and you won't be able to use `document('file.html')` sucessfully. But in your case it seems that operation works but you failed to ensure your root element is copied, so you end up with two top level elements in the result document which is then not XML as there needs to be a single root element. So add

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in your XSLT and the result will be a well-formed XML document with a single root element.

That rather cryptic error message basically tells you that the markup following the first result element does not match the `Misc` production in the XML specification which only allows comments and/or processing instructions following the single allowed root element.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything works just fine now! I didn't really realize i was missing the root element and that it's mandatory. Again, thank you, i learned a lot. =)